# Refactor multiple "if" in C#

Tags: c#, refactoring, if-statement

```
for (int i = lstReportCount - 1; i >= 0; i--){
if (   (input.ServiceTypes == "1" && lstReport[i].A == 0)
    || (input.ServiceTypes == "2" && lstReport[i].B == 0)
    || (input.ServiceTypes == "3" && lstReport[i].C == 0)
    || (input.ServiceTypes == "4" && lstReport[i].D == 0)
    || (input.ServiceTypes == "1,2" && lstReport[i].A == 0 && lstReport[i].B == 0)
    || (input.ServiceTypes == "1,3" && lstReport[i].A == 0 && lstReport[i].C == 0)
    || (input.ServiceTypes == "1,4" && lstReport[i].A == 0 && lstReport[i].D == 0)
    || (input.ServiceTypes == "2,4" && lstReport[i].B == 0 && lstReport[i].D == 0)
    || (input.ServiceTypes == "3,2" && lstReport[i].C == 0 && lstReport[i].B == 0)
    || (input.ServiceTypes == "3,4" && lstReport[i].C == 0 && lstReport[i].D == 0)
    || (input.ServiceTypes == "1,3,2" && lstReport[i].A == 0 && lstReport[i].C == 0 && lstReport[i].B == 0)
    || (input.ServiceTypes == "1,3,4" && lstReport[i].A == 0 && lstReport[i].C == 0 && lstReport[i].D == 0)
    || (input.ServiceTypes == "1,2,4" && lstReport[i].A == 0 && lstReport[i].B == 0 && lstReport[i].D == 0)
    || (input.ServiceTypes == "3,2,4" && lstReport[i].C == 0 && lstReport[i].B == 0 && lstReport[i].D == 0))
    {
        lstReport.Remove(lstReport[i]);
    }}
```

The method I wrote uses a series of "if" statements. It works fine, but I would like to think about maintainability of the method in future, and would really like to refactor it to something cleaner.

Can you give advice on any approach which would improve the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number in the `ServiceTypes` string must match the the member A, B, C, D, right? So start by providing a function which makes access to those members possible by an index. Something along the lines of:

```
int GetMember(Report report,int j)   // I assume lstReport[i] is of type "Report"
{
  switch(j)
  {
      case 1:  return report.A;      
      case 2:  return report.B;
      case 3:  return report.C;
      case 4:  return report.D;
      default: throw ArgumentException();
  }
}
```

What remains is to split the string `input.ServiceTypes` into integer indexes and use those:

```
bool TestIfMembersOfServiceTypesAreZero(string serviceTypes, Report report)
{
    int[] indexes = serviceTypes.Split(",").Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
    // add some exception handling here if you expect int.Parse to fail
    return indexes.Length>0 && indexes.All(i => GetMember(report,i) == 0);
}
```

Finally, call the function like

```
 if(TestIfMembersOfServiceTypesAreZero(input.ServiceTypes,lstReport[i]))
      lstReport.Remove(lstReport[i]);
```

(Beware, I did neither compile nor test the code, but I guess you get the idea).